# python xml.etree.ElementTree tostring() fromstring() roundtrip fails for unicode code points

Tags: python, xml, unicode, elementtree

I'm using `xml.etree.ElementTree` in python 2.7 and having problems round-tripping to-and-from strings.  Calling `ET.fromstring()` on `ET.tostring()` fails if there are non-ascii Unicode characters in the tree.

Why doesn't this work?  Given that `ElementTree` wants bytestreams and to do its own decoding, why then does it default to a ASCII parser?  Is this determined by something I've overlooked, like the encoding of the python file or locale?

1. ASCII only chars work:

   ```
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

   t1 = ET.Element('test')
   t1.text = u'hello world'
   t1_roundtrip = ET.fromstring(ET.tostring(t1, encoding='utf8', method='xml'))
   # ET.dump(t1) == ET.dump(t1_roundtrip)
   ```
2. Unicode Code points fail:

   ```
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

   t2 = ET.Element('test')
   t2.text = u'\u2603'
   t2_roundtrip = ET.fromstring(ET.tostring(t2, encoding='utf8', method='xml'))

   >>> t2_roundtrip = ET.fromstring(ET.tostring(t2, encoding='utf8', method='xml'))
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1300, in XML
       parser.feed(text)
     File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1642, in feed
       self._raiseerror(v)
     File "/opt/rh/python27/root/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1506, in _raiseerror
       raise err
   xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 2, column 6
   ```

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: And, do you have a question?

Comment: Curious what my cognitive failure is in understanding ET's view of the world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified an illegal encoding. Quoting the [ElementTree doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#id5):

> > The encoding string included in XML output should conform to the appropriate standards. For example, “UTF-8” is valid, but “UTF8” is not. See http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#NT-EncodingDecl and http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets.

Comment: Good to know. Wish the incorrect "utf8" would trigger an exception, that would make such error much easier to debug. SMH.

Answer (score 0):

Found two ways around this:

1. don't include encoding for `tostring()`:

   ```
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
   t3 = ET.Element('test')
   t3.text = u'\u2603'
   t3_roundtrip = ET.fromstring(ET.tostring(t3, method='xml'))
   ```
2. specify `XMLParser` with utf-8 encoding:

   ```
   import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
   t4 = ET.Element('test')
   t4.text = u'\u2603'
   t4_roundtrip_utf = ET.fromstring(
       ET.tostring(t3, encoding='utf8', method='xml'),
       parser=ET.XMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
   ```

Why do I need either?  Aren't XML files utf-8 unless specified otherwise?